# Deploying a Zend Framework site on Free Web Host

Tags: zend-framework, hosting

I have this small showcase project written in Zend Framework and I would need to deploy it on the web for a few months. Money is extremely tight , close to non-existent , so a free web host would be ideal .

After extensive google-ing , and some trial and errors with a few of these services , I'm still unable to say that I found a free web host that would behave decently with a Zend Framework installation . Do you guys know of any ? Thanks

Comment: What types of errors are you encountering with free hosts?  Include paths? PHP in safe mode?  More details will help us answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF dont needs installing :). Find any free host with php support, upload ZF library, set proper include_path in your app and that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

just upload your files , and copy the files in /library/Zend/* from the original download to your host.

/library/ is already defined in include_path by the Bootstrap.